# Get CountVectorizer to include "1:1"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

If I have some text that includes the phrase "1:1". How do I get `CountVectorizer` to recognize that as a token?

```
text = ["first ques # 1:1 on stackoverflow", "please help"]
vec = CountVectorizer()
vec.fit_transform(text)

vec.get_feature_names()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a customized tokenizer. For simple cases replacing

```
vec = CountVectorizer()
```

by

```
vec = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda s: s.split())
```

would do. With this modification your code returns:

```
[u'#', u'1:1', u'first', u'help', u'on', u'please', u'ques', u'stackoverflow']
```

Hopefully this suggestion will put you on the right track, but notice that such workaround would not work properly in more complex cases (for example if your text has punctuation marks).

To deal with puntuation marks, you could pass `CountVectorizer` a token pattern like this:

```
text = [u"first ques... # 1:1, on stackoverflow", u"please, help!"]
vec = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=u'\w:?\w+')
```

Output:

```
[u'1:1', u'first', u'help', u'on', u'please', u'ques', u'stackoverflow']
```

Comment: Yeah, what arem y options if my text has punctuation marks?